# Count specific numbers from a column from an input file linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, search, count

i was trying to read a file and count a specific number at a specific place and show how many times it appears, for example:
1st field are numbers, 2nd field brand name, 3rd field a group they belong to, 4th and 5th not important.

```
1:audi:2:1990:5
2:bmw:2:1987:4
3:bugatti:3:1988:19
4.buick:4:2000:12
5:dodge:2:1999:4
6:ferrari:2:2000:4
```

As an output, i want to search by column 3, and group together 2's(by brand name) and count how many of them i have. 
The output i am looking for should look like this:

```
1:audi:2:1990:5
2:bmw:2:1987:4
5:dodge:2:1999:4
6:ferrari:2:2000:4
```

4  -> showing how many lines there are. 
I have tried taken this approach but can't figure it out:

```
file="cars.txt"; sort -t ":" -k3 $file   #sorting by the 3rd field
grep -c '2' cars.txt   # this counts all the 2's in the file including number 2.
```

I hope you understand. and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by "group together by brand name", but the following will get you the output that you describe.

```
awk -F':' '$3 == 2' Input.txt
```

If you want a line count, you can pipe that to `wc -l`.

```
awk -F':' '$3 == 2' Input.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: thank you for the help merlin. i was trying to be able to output lines that have 2 in the third field. i just tested your code and it does the counting but how can i just show those lines that contain 2?

Comment: If you use the first one without the line count, you will get all lines that have `2` in the third field.

Comment: that would simply put them in order and the lines with 2 will be listed last, am i right? i just tested that

Comment: I'm not sure what version of `awk` you have on your system, but my version only prints the lines with `2` in the third column. The ordering is completely based on the order in which the lines appear in the original file.

Comment: GREAT! had a sort command line somewhere that was sorting all the lines all over again and adding at the end the lines with 2. thank you again. appreciate it a lot

Comment: @endri, You are welcome. I'm glad it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess line 4 is 4:buick and not 4.buick. Then I suggest this

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} $3~2{total++;print} END{print "TOTAL --- "total}' Input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain `bash` solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=":" read -ra line; do
if (( ${line[2]} == 2 )); then
    IFS=":" && echo "${line[*]}"
    (( count++ ))
fi
done < file
echo "Count = $count"
```

#### Output:

```
1:audi:2:1990:5
2:bmw:2:1987:4
5:dodge:2:1999:4
6:ferrari:2:2000:4
Count = 4
```